# Create a function removeFromPlaylist that accepts two arguments (the playlist object and the artist name)

Tags: javascript

Create a function `removeFromPlaylist` that accepts two arguments (the playlist object and the artist name). The body of the function should delete the key-value pair from the playlist and return the updated playlist.

I couldn't past this test with the below code:

```
function removeFromPlaylist(playlist, artistName) {
  delete playlist.artistName
  return playlist
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deletion of the key you have to use the brackets **delete playlist[artistName];** because otherwise it tries to delete "artistName" burt you want to delete the key with the value of artistName.

```js
function removeFromPlaylist(playlist, artistName) {
  delete playlist[artistName];
  return playlist;
}


let playlist = { song: 'Hello', artist: "Madonna", duration: "2:34" };

console.log ( removeFromPlaylist( playlist, "artist") );
```